# Kubernetes executor on Gitlab: failed to fit in any node fit failure summary on nodes : MatchNodeSelector (3)

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I treied to configure Kubernetes executor for gitlab CI, but I get this error on runner Pods:

```
failed to fit in any node
fit failure summary on nodes : MatchNodeSelector (3)
```

Anyone has idea what can be wrong?